# Querying Hyperledger Fabric using fabcar example against a custom network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently trying to work out querying a Fabric network using the fabcar example as a starting point.

I have an ubuntu 16.04 vm up with a modified byfn network.

This is the error I keep returning.

```
zonked@couchdb-fabric:~/fabric-samples/fabcar$ sudo node query.js
Store path:/home/zonked/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: 
Error: Stream removed
    at /home/zonked/fabric-
samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15
Query has completed, checking results
error from query =  { Error: Stream removed
at /home/zonked/fabric-
samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15 code: 2, 
metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

Answer (score 0):

When Fabcar is using a traditional network (i.e. basic-network from fabric-samples), the setup process requests certificates from Fabric-CA and then puts user certificates into ~/.hfc-key-store. Fabcar .js scripts search for an identity wallet there.

First-network (byfn) does not generate a Fabric-CA infrastructure (compare docker-compose.yaml from this network with the one from basic-network used by fabcar). Therefore, you may need to copy and prepare certificates on your own or modify byfn to include Fabric-CA.

Private and public key you may want to try to copy to the identity wallet and generated by Byfn are placed in /first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin\@org1.example.com/msp/keystore and /first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin\@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts.

Comment: I worked out it was timing out due to my chaincode. I developed my chaincode without couchdb so when I moved onto a network that includes it, it takes longer than it should. I'm just going to modify my chaincode for now, and move to a custom network without couchdb later.